# How to fix the best overloaded method match has some invalid arguments?

Tags: c#

I am getting the error in the title, what is wrong with the code? I think its a syntax error, but I'm not sure as I don't have much information on what the error actually means.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Please Input Number of Rows you want to make in your pyrimid: ");

        int num = int.Parse(Console.Read()); // error here

        Console.WriteLine(num);// Just to check if it is getting the right number
        Console.Read();//This is Here just so the console window doesn't close when the program runs

    }
}
}
```

#### Edit:

Just to Clarify, I want the code just to get a number from the user and then print the number the user inputted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`int.Parse` accepts a string as parameter. Use `Console.ReadLine()` to get a string from user and then pass it into `int.Parse`

```
int num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Note that this will throw `FormatException` if the user will enter something not recognisable as `int`. If you are not sure, that the user will input a good number (I always don't), use `TryParse`. Example is given below

```
int value;

if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out value))
    Console.WriteLine("parsed number as: {0}", value);
else
    Console.WriteLine("incorrect number format");
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Console.Read() returns an int, but int.Parse is expecting a string. Simply change it to

```
int num =Console.Read();
```

Comment: I have done this, but then it returns the ASCII number and not the number itself

Comment: @user2224223 replace Console.Read() with Console.ReadLine() in Your code

Comment: I don't think, that OP want an `ASCII` representation of user input. Besides it takes only first `char` in input

Comment: `It's better to use Console.ReadLine()` which returns a string then create a variable of int in your code that converts the string input from the console to an integer

Answer (score 1):

### `Console.Read()` and ASCII

This is occurring because [`Console.Read()`](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read.aspx&ei=XZJVUeOfK4rUkAWzuYCQAw&usg=AFQjCNFlewuITgj6ELVvD2S7oVoS5u-Cxw&bvm=bv.44442042,d.dGI) actually returns and `int`, not a `string`. It returns the ASCII code of the key that was pressed, you will need to convert it to a char then to a string and then parse it.

```
var val = int.Parse(((char)Console.Read()).ToString());
```

Note that `Console.Read()` will not return the integer in the format you think, values `0` to `9` actually come out at `60` to `70` as they're the **key codes** not the characters you pressed.

[See the ASCII table here](http://www.asciitable.com/)

### `Console.ReadLine()`

An alternative and probably better solution would be to use [`Console.ReadLine()`](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/system.console.readline.aspx&ei=WZJVUeGBKon0lAWA8YHIDg&usg=AFQjCNGQ3SSqv6maaLYvnHzo5Bir1sDi5Q&bvm=bv.44442042,d.dGI) which returns a `string`

```
var val = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

### Warning

You should always be careful when using [`int.Parse()`](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse.aspx&ei=YZJVUcK1LYfvlAW5pIHICw&usg=AFQjCNHQUKICz4gfgfKygtnYm0j_XZ_hMQ&bvm=bv.44442042,d.dGI) as it will throw an exception if the string provided is not numeric. A better option is to use [`int.TryParse()`](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx&ei=ZJJVUYziEIK8kAW9w4DADQ&usg=AFQjCNFsVKYA0wc120ikLcXFOxNPRxRGcw&bvm=bv.44442042,d.dGI) which you give an `out` argument and it returns whether parsing was successful.

```
string text = Console.ReadLine();
int val;
if (int.TryParse(text, out val))
{
    // It is a number
}
{
    // It is not a number
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting that, is because Console.Read returns an int

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read.aspx

And it can't parse an int, it can only parse strings.

You probabily want Console.ReadLine - which returns a string.